# Are there other traditional Chinese zhuyin input other than the default?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, input-method

In 12.04, there is only one traditional Chinese zhuyin input: Chewing

However, Chewing has many features I do not like.

The most annoying one is that Chewing randomly drops characters after you type too many characters and fill the "queue". For example, Chewing outputs this when I type 1~10 (一二三四五六七八九十) repeatedly many times:

一四五七十一四五六七八九十一二三四五六七八九十
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
expected:
一二三四五六七八九十一二三四五六七八九十一二三四五六七八九十

Chewing drops the characters 二三六八九二三 (2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 2, 3).

This is very annoying and obstructive. Are there any other traditional Chinese Zhuyin packages I could try out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ibus-m17n](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ibus-m17n) [image: Install ibus-m17n] and [ibus-anthy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ibus-anthy) [image: Install ibus-anthy] both provide BoPoMoFo input methods.

Ibus input methods are for both traditional and simplified characters. To switch, you need to show the language panel.

*Right click the Ibus indicator on the menubar >> Choose Preferences*.

In the *Preferences* dialog, change the *Show language panel* setting from the default *Embedded in menu* to either *When active* or *Always*. Close the dialog. (The *Embedded in menu* option does not always work.)

The language panel usually opens in the lower right, but you can drag it around. You will see a toggle button for 简/繁 (simplified/traditional) on the bar.

Comment: But Bopomofo is outputs simplified Chinese. I'm looking for trad. Chinese alternatives. Thank for your input though.

Comment: It inputs both types. I added instructions to the answer.

Comment: @some-noob-student Have you had a chance to try the traditional input with ibus?

Comment: Oh yes, I was so satisfied I forgot about the answer that lead me to it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.